# Setting custom UINavigationBar class more than once

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationbar

I have a `UITabBarController` which has 3 `UINavigationController`s and 2 `UIViewController`, the 2 `UIViewController`s have a `UINavigationBar` in each of them.

My question is, how do I give all 5 `UINavigationBar`s a custom class?

I want to override the background image (using the iOS5 technique) on each of them, however, when I create a custom class, I cannot set it more to more than one of these in IB.

Does anyone have a solution?

Thanks in advance as always!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake.

I was trying to apply the UINavigationBar class to a UINavigationItem.

To overcome this, I turned all of the UINavigation children of the UITabBarController into UINavigationController's, subclassed it and applied it to all of them.